Does temporarily withdrawing from a degree program fall under "required to leave" when applying again for a UK visa to resume studies?
Does temporarily withdrawing from a degree program fall under "required to leave" when applying again for a UK visa to resume studies?

Please ask questions about student visas on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com.
